# How to use TextArea under Android?

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.6

I'm trying to build a basic page with some editable text using the `TextArea` control. Everything works fine under desktop (windows), but there are several problems with Android.

Q5.6/windows mingw. android-23 build, min API 16/target 23 (Android 6.0)

The problems are:

1. If i subclass the `TextAreaStyle` it breaks Android. The selection handles disappear (amongst other weirdness).
2. Using rich text, links are not clickable, even with `onLinkActivated`. they work fine on desktop. The link underlines also disappear after a bit of scrolling.
3. There is no cut & paste popup on Android. I've seen this posted already as a QT bug. is there any progress on this, or workaround. I've seen a workaround for Qt5.4, but this doesn't work on 5.6.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQml 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 800

    function makeText() {
        var s = "click <a href=\"http://qt.io\">here</a>\n"
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            s += 
"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras at tempus felis. Nulla facilisi. Duis quam purus, posuere eu rutrum vel, blandit quis lorem. Cras vitae orci eget lorem luctus cursus quis nec nibh. Sed luctus ligula urna, vel commodo nisi finibus quis. Donec pretium eu purus a porttitor. Nam vehicula nunc quis dui gravida luctus. Morbi fermentum, elit nec ullamcorper accumsan, ex ligula iaculis nisi, id pretium ipsum metus quis quam. In lobortis dignissim semper. Aenean at neque lorem. Maecenas dapibus, arcu a condimentum consequat, mauris enim vehicula nibh, in fringilla quam nisi eu ipsum.</p>"
        }
        return s
    }

    TextArea {
        id: textarea
        anchors.fill: parent

        // putting this in breaks selection handles in android, why?
        // no putting it in makes desktop look bad.
        //TextAreaStyle { renderType: Text.QtRendering }

        font.pointSize: 16
        textMargin: 16
        textFormat: TextEdit.RichText

        frameVisible: false
        flickableItem.flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        text: Qt.platform.os + "\n" + makeText()

        // works desktop, fails android, why?
        onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally(link)

        // there is no cut & paste menu either? 
    }
}
```

I'm battling all this problems just to get a simple page of text.

gist code, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5a9e9751e10db22695e2643e8191292

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: 1) Styling removes the Android styling. Selection handles are made in QML so also they are removed by your customization. 2) A bug? 3) Quick controls 1 are not developed any more. New controls are in development and you can give the new [`TextArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-controls-textarea.html) a try. I'm not sure selection handlers are present though as developer wanted to hook up to native ones (instead of relying on a QML implementation).

Comment: on (1), is there any way around this? The only solution i have so far is to make separate versions of the file. (3) I tried 5.7RC and, it seems, they've removed the cut&paste menu altogether - even for desktops. very odd.

Comment: 1) I don't think so. If you have to do some small changes then possibly yes. But if yours is a totally different style, no there's no (easy) way. Hopefully someone else can help on this. 3) Probably post-poned to 5.8, then. You're not lucky.